# Workflow: create item in list

Tags: workflow

An existing workflow has a step as follows. It performs as required. I'm trying to migrate it to a new site collection however when I click OK it will produce an error 'Please specify a value for all required * fields'. If I select a value for App Name (*) it will work but this is not what is required. My question is how was the original workflow created like this? I am using SP Designer 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that **App Name** column did not exist or it was not mandatory when the workflow was created and published.

Ideally, you would have a technical documentation at hand or the ability to ask the author if my guess is correct.